# How to save data in Sanskrit language to Excel in Python

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding

I want to save the data from the following page into an Excel sheet using Python. Can anyone please tell me which encoding should I use so that the data is saved in correct format?

http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:5.apte